# Read data from different result sets using SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, sqldatareader

We are migrating our data into another database. I'm writing simple app that downloads data and serializes it to XML files.

I have a stored procedure that returns several result sets. Those tables are related. Let's say, there are *customers*, *customer_addresses* and *customer_products*

On the client side I need to take first customer, get all data related to that customer, and serialize it.
In this way I won't need to keep all the data in memory, it will be serialized sequentially right away to the file

My problem is that I'm trying to use `SqlDataReader` to avoid downloading all the data at once from database.
But with one `SqlDataReader` I can't jump from one result set to another and start from the right position.

Ok, I tried to use multiple active result sets for those purpose. But it's single solid stored procedure. Having several `SqlDataReader`'s on it leads to executing this stored procedure several times.

Any ideas?
I need to easily jump from one result set to another and reading data from the right position
(Take first customer, get all related data, take second customer, get all related data, etc.)

Comment: Also, if you have a better title for this question, write it here please. Because current title doesn't imply that I need to switch from different result sets back and forth while saving current position in each set.

Comment: How much data are you reading? AFAIK this could not be done with a DataReader. You need to read everything from the first result and then go to the NextResult. A Dataset instead can have relations defined to link data but you need to have everything in memory

Comment: @Steve potentially up to dozens GB

Comment: Then I suggest you to import every table to a matching temporary table on the destination database and then move data directly inside that database using the native tools. Something like BulkCopy could help to make things faster.

Comment: @DenVys, you have to fully read each recordsets returned by SP and call reader.NextResult() when finishing reading data from one recordset. If your SP returns too many data - better to rewrite this procedure.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are business requirements that i can't change :). I have to export all data to XML file. I can't download all the data on client at once, i can't keep all the serialized data in memory. Therefore, I need the sequential way on how to do it.

Comment: If you are building an xml file then do it in sections. Do one query in the database and then write data to xml.  Then repeat with next query.  Serialization take a lot of resource and you can create the xml using other c# Libraries.

Comment: But writing those I comments I thought about one idea. If I have no other choice, I can download all customers and then make an subquery to the database for each customer. So, I think rubber duck approach helped here :)

Comment: Why not restore a backup to the destination as a temporary database?  Then do your sync as you wish.  If the destination is not in use, then perhaps replication.

Comment: Use power shell to loop[ through each table and bcp to a xml file.  bcp "select * from Test.dbo.Table for xml auto" queryout 'E:\Export\Tabe.xml' -S .\DEV -d Test -T -w  When importing, remove all FKs prior and add them back after.  It's xml, so maybe it meets the requirements.